# How to run a website that uses npm to start the server

Tags: node.js, installation, web, server, setup-deployment

Me and a few friends have been working on developing some experiments. I want to put them up on a URL so we can all share them with other people.

I however, have no experience setting a server up for anything other then static web pages.

Within my `package.json` file there's a command that I run in my terminal window to build which is: `npm run watch & serve public/ -p 1618`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && serve --compress public/ -p 1618",
    "dev": "npm run watch & serve public/ -p 1618",
  },
```

How do I set this up so it's on a URL? Like a website basically, I have the domain name just don't know where or how to set this up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signup for the free Heroku account and upgrade if needed. https://www.heroku.com/beta-pricing

Here is their deploy instructions for node.js.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Another host with a free option is OpenShift.